# Filter rows in df1 using conditions for passfail coluimn in df2

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes like this

**df1**

```
Measurement <- c("Length","Breadth","Height","Width")
When <- c("2017-04-07 15:19:02", "2017-02-10 09:13:10", "2017-01-13 11:45:14", "2016-11-13 21:35:24")
Fail <- c(2,3,2,3)
Pass <- c(2,2,4,2)
df1 <- data.frame(Measurement,When,Fail,Pass)
df1$When <- as.POSIXct(df1$When)
```

**df2**

```
Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Length","Length",
                 "Breadth","Breadth","Breadth","Breadth","Breadth",
                 "Height","Height","Height","Height","Height","Height",
                 "Width","Width","Width","Width","Width")
Datetime <- c("2017-04-08 15:19:02","2017-04-09 15:19:02","2017-04-09 16:19:02","2017-04-10 15:19:02",
              "2017-02-11 09:13:10","2017-02-12 09:13:10","2017-02-13 09:13:10","2017-02-14 09:13:10","2017-02-15 09:13:10",
              "2017-01-19 11:45:14","2017-01-20 11:45:14","2017-01-21 11:45:14","2017-01-23 11:45:14","2017-01-27 11:45:14","2017-01-13 11:45:14",
              "2016-11-12 21:35:24","2016-11-14 21:35:24","2016-11-17 21:35:24","2016-11-19 21:35:24","2016-11-19 23:35:24")
PassFail <- c("Fail","Fail","Pass","Pass",
              "Fail","Pass","Fail","Fail","Pass",
              "Fail","Fail","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass",
              "Fail","Fail","Pass","Fail","Pass")
df2 <- data.frame(Measurement,Datetime,PassFail)
df2$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime)
```

df1 has the pass and fail counts reported from df2 for each measurement. I am trying to filter the df1 data frame using the following conditions.

1. For each row in df1, I want to look into df2 to check if the **first 2 measurements** (sorted by the Datetime) are consecutive fails. I want to retain that measurement row in df1.
2. I also want to check the above condition **only** when "Datetime" in df2 > "When" in df1.

My **desired output** would be

```
Measurement                When Fail Pass
       Length 2017-04-07 15:19:02    2    2
       Height 2017-01-13 11:45:14    2    4
```

I got the counts in df1 using this way but not able to filter it to retain the rows of interest according to the above logic.

```
setDT(df1)[, When := as.POSIXct(When)]
setDT(df2)[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)]
df1[df2, on=.(Measurement, Datetime > When), 
              if (.N > 0L) as.list(table(PassFail)), by=.EACHI]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I also would like a fast filter solution since I want to apply it to a larger dataset.

Comment: Your last line is almost right. Could do `df1[ df2[df1, on=.(Measurement, Datetime > When), all(head(x.PassFail, 2) == "Fail"), by=.EACHI]$V1 ]` Regarding the if (.N > 0L) check, I think you can instead set nomatch=0 in the join.

Comment: Fantastic. Love this solution. Thanks much Frank :-) Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor extension to the OP's code:

```
df1[ 
  df2[df1, on=.(Measurement, Datetime > When), 
    all(head(x.PassFail, 2) == "Fail")
  , by=.EACHI]$V1 
]
```

Comment: It *should* be possible to write `.SD` in place of the inner `df1`, but I guess there might be a bug.